# Retrieving an <li>'s number

Tags: javascript, html

This outputs **cxxiii. Lorem**:

```html
<ol start="123" style="list-style-type: lower-roman">
  <li>Lorem</li>
</ol>
```

Is there any way to get the "cxxiii" from the LI element using JavaScript?

`value` seems to be the only attribute of [LI elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), but that always returns a `0` for me:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('li').value);
```

```html
<ol start="123" style="list-style-type: lower-roman">
  <li>Lorem</li>
</ol>
```

I'd prefer a solution that works with any `list-style-type`.

Comment: Thanks @cale_b, I somehow missed that.  That goes back 4 years, so I'll wait a bit to see if someone posts a solution before deleting.

Comment: Certainly - I'd love to see if / how it's possible!  Seems like there should be a way....

Comment: doubt there is a way to get it.

Comment: It's really odd, but there is no way to get the computer generated index values of **li**. At least not without some ugly hack and even then it still remains impossible.